# D&D 4e: way to transfer ongoing damage from an ally to my character?

Tags: dnd-4e

I have a wizard (multiclassed as a bard, if that matters) who wants to transfer ongoing damage from an ally to himself. I know I've seen something that does this, but can't remember where.

I don't want it use the armor slot if at all possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Armor of Sacrifice does this as an at-will for adjacent allies, but it won't work for most wizards because it's chain, scale, or plate armor only.

You do have some power options. The easy one for you is Ode of Sacrifice: level 6 bard power which can transfer any condition that a save can end. It can be transferred to you or to another ally, and you provide a bonus to saves against that condition.

There's also Cycle of Change; it's a heroic tier feat that allows you to transfer any effect that a save can end to yourself from an ally as an encounter power. Unfortunately, it requires that you worship a deity with the change domain and you must have the Channel Divinity class feature. You could get that, but you have to multiclass into a divine class and then paragon multiclass, which is not entirely efficient.

Paladins have Touch of Grace, a paladin level 2 utility power that has the same effect. Clerics have Healer's Balm at level 10, which transfers all the effects on your ally to you.

I looked through all heroic and paragon items that mention ongoing damage and didn't find anything else. There are a few ways to get ongoing damage from you to an enemy, for the sake of completeness: the Transference Weapon has the ability to transfer ongoing damage (or any other condition) from you to an enemy you hit. Shared Suffering Armor gives an enemy ongoing damage when you are initially affected with ongoing damage. Skin of Agonies, also armor, does the same thing and gives you automatic saves against untyped ongoing damage. Ring of Unwelcome Gifting allows you to transfer ongoing from you to an enemy when you hit them with a basic attack.

Comment: Oh, you know, you probably were thinking of that. I'll edit my answer, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for a good list! It does look like _Ode to Sacrifice_ is the best idea so far.

Comment: Betrayal of Body, a feat from The Book of Vile Darkness, allows you to transfer ongoing damage to an ally, increasing it by 5.  So if your ally took the feat they could send it your way.